# Python throwing out a random invalid syntax error

Tags: python

Version: Python 3.3.2 (default, Sep 11 2013, 20:16:42)

Hey,
I'm doing some tests with python, fiddling a bit with the shell, but I get a strange error.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> if a > 0:  
...     print("a is a positive number.")
... if a < 0:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    if a < 0:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why this error appears. I know I can use elif or else, but I just want to test.
Help?

Comment: Use [IPython shell](http://ipython.org/) to code such multi-line statements in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you pressing backspace to enter the second `if`? The shell doesn't like that. It's expecting another line in the logic block, or to be able to execute the block (by pressing enter one more time). The shell can only execute one block at a time, i.e. finish the first `if` first, then you can enter the second `if`. You can use `elif` because it's still considered part of the same logic block.

Answer (score 4):

This is valid Python syntax when it is located in a module, but in the interactive interpreter you need to separate blocks of code with a blank line.

The handy rule of thumb here is that you can't start a new block with `if`, `def`, `class`, `for`, `while`, `with`, or `try` unless you have the `>>>` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The REPL is still working on the previous code block. Enter an empty line on its own to terminate it first.

Answer (score 0):

You need a blank line after your `print` statement, the Python interpreter thinks you're continuing a block until you do that, so you get an indentation error on your second `if` statement. This is not "invalid", the interactive interpreter is designed to work that way.